# How to reverse items in WPF Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, reverse

If i have DataGrid which looks like:

```
Col 1   Col 2
------- -------
1       a
2       b
3       c
...     ...
n       n
```

Can the order be reversed easily without sorting? So that n is first, and 1 is last. I have custom sort implemented from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/28/improving-microsoft-datagrid-sorting-performance-part-3.aspx) article, but sorting the same column twice in a row calls sorting function twice (which is slow), so just reversing the order should be faster and have the same effect.

Comment: I don't think many people will download and unzip source code to help you.  It would help a lot if you included relevant parts of the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If You want reverse data before binding (and You have possibilities to access to data) may You use [Reverse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) in codebehind ? I don't know what is source of Your data so I can't help more :/

Comment: My code is very similar to the one from the article i mentioned, just the columns are different. Example of how to change code from that article would be more than enough.

Comment: too much problematic example like for me ;/